# PHP - Echo variable issue

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I have a table that has the user email address and password stored inside it. i want to display the email of the user on page load, when the user logs into their account for the first time. But it is not working. The data does not appear in the text field. I believe my code should work in theory.

HTML

```
<section class="container">
        <form id="myform " class="Form" method="post" action="Cus_Account.php" accept-charset="utf-8">

            <!--                    <div id="first">-->
            <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" value="" required> 
            <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" value="" required>
            <input type="text" id="email" name="email" value="<?php echo $email; ?>" required>
            <input type="number" id="phone" name="phone" value="" required>
            <input type="submit" name="Update" value="Update">
            <br>
        </form>
```

PHP

```
   <?php
        $user = $_SESSION['Cus_Email'];

        $get_user = "SELECT Cus_Email FROM Cus_Register WHERE Cus_Email='$user'";

        $run_user = mysqli_query($dbc, $get_user);
        //check if customer is on databse
        $row_customer = mysqli_fetch_array($run_user);


        $email = $row_customer['Cus_Email'];

        ?>
```

It may help to tell you i have another query running on the page also

PHP

```
      <?php
        if (isset($_POST['Update'])) {
            echo $c_fname = $_POST['fname'];
            echo $c_lname = $_POST['lname'];
            echo $c_phone = $_POST['phone'];



            $insert_det = "INSERT INTO Cus_acc_details(CUS_Fname,CUS_Lname, CUS_Phone) VALUES (?,?,?)";
            $stmt = mysqli_prepare($dbc, $insert_det);

            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ssi', $c_fname, $c_lname, $c_phone);

            /* execute query */
            $r = mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

            if ($insert_det) {
                echo " Saved";
            }
        } else {
            echo "<b> Error </b>";
        }
        ?>
```

This query inserts data that as has not been collected on the sign up page into the database.

Error:

> Undefined index: Cus_Email in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/PhpProject2/customer/Cus_Account.php on line 60

Comment: Any errors? Does the query run? You should use parameterized queries everywhere. The `HTML` is on the `PHP` page?

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put user data, even from `$_SESSION`, data directly into a query.

Comment: Don't expect a magic answer. Consult these following links http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php
and apply that to your code.

Comment: @chris85 yes the html and php are on the same page. The error is " Undefined index: Cus_Email in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/PhpProject2/customer/Cus_Account.php on line 60" which is  $user = $_SESSION['Cus_Email'];

Comment: Is `$_SESSION['Cus_Email']` set? Did you start the session?

Comment: add this as the top line of php:  session_start();

Comment: But does it insert successfully in your `Cus_acc_details` table?

Comment: @chris85 yes the session is started at the very top.

Comment: @LoganWayne yeah that works perfectly. it is getting the email to echo is my problem

Comment: And it has a primary/unique ID key on your `Cus_acc_details` table? And your code is all in a same file?

Comment: @LoganWayne yes it does and yes everything is in the same table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `var_dump` to console log the data to  make`Cus_Email`.

If you can't find it,you could check if your sql is right.

```
<?php
    $user = $_SESSION['Cus_Email'];

    $get_user = "SELECT Cus_Email FROM Cus_Register WHERE Cus_Email='$user'";

    $run_user = mysqli_query($dbc, $get_user);
    //check if customer is on databse
    $row_customer = mysqli_fetch_array($run_user);
    // to test
    var_dump($row_customer);
    $email = $row_customer['Cus_Email'];

?>
```